# How to get the CSS Style of the last selected DOM using Chrome inspect tools?

Tags: dom, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector, code-inspection

$0 is used to select the last selected DOM, But i want to get the CSS style of  that selected tools.
when i type this
`$0.style` it give me this output

"CSSStyleDeclaration {accentColor: '', additiveSymbols: '', alignContent: '', alignItems: '', alignSelf: '', …}"

I just want when i access using the $0 example `<div class="my-class"></div>` whatever css properties applied it show me such as margin, padding etc